# Inserting many items to multiple relationship tables in parallel in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 1M html files that I need to parse and then insert the extracted information into my sql server. Each file parsed out information end up in multiple tables due to relationships among the objects I have parsed out

I am using Entity Framework right now to do this but adding each piece of my information to the proper object on the EF context takes a long time and not efficient! I need this faster especially that I have so many file to process.

What is the fasted way to parse out a lot of file in parallel and insert it in SQL server where items you are adding have relationships?

Also, is there a better technology for this? Like Informatica?

Comment: I wonder why did you use EF for such scenario? Btw. if you need to add that data in transaction you will not be able to use parallel approach.

Comment: Well, I have EF for the rest of this DB utilization for read and query but I have to construct the DB first and my initial attemp was to use the model I have already build in EF but it is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) will be the best option in this case.

You can make a generic wrapper around `SqlBulkCopy` class, which will allow you to use `SqlBulkCopy` on any entity. Below is the wrapper for LINQ-to-SQL, but the same idea will work with Entity Framework, with the assumption that your entity mapped to tables one-to-one.

```
public void BulkInsert<TBusinessObject>(IEnumerable<TBusinessObject> entities, int timeoutInSeconds)
    where TBusinessObject : class, IBusinessObject
{
    AssertUtilities.ArgumentAllNotNull(entities, "entities");
    AssertUtilities.ArgumentNotNegative(timeoutInSeconds, "timeoutInSeconds");

    var metaTable = Mapping.GetTable(typeof(TBusinessObject));
    if (metaTable == null)
        throw new DataAccessException("MetaTable is not found.");
    var insertDataMembers = metaTable.RowType.PersistentDataMembers
        .Where(arg => !arg.IsDbGenerated)
        .OrderBy(arg => arg.Ordinal)
        .ToList();
    using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
    {
        dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var dataColumns = insertDataMembers
            .Select(arg => new DataColumn(arg.MappedName))
            .ToArray();
        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(dataColumns);
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var itemArray = insertDataMembers
                .Select(arg => arg.StorageAccessor.GetBoxedValue(entity))
                .ToArray();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(itemArray);
        }
        try
        {
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                Connection.Open();
            var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)Connection;
            var sqlTransaction = (SqlTransaction)Transaction;
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTransaction))
            {
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = timeoutInSeconds;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = metaTable.TableName;
                foreach (var dataColumn in dataColumns)
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, dataColumn.ColumnName);
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw DataAccessExceptionTranslator.Translate(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to persist each my parsed out object and its related object at once to multiple table at the same maintaining the relationships. Sounds like SqlBulkCopy only does persisting to one table only but what if I need to persist to multiple tables where primary keys are all auto generated? I am not sure if my question is clear.

Comment: @Mike Dotnet - if you want to return id after every single row insert, then you don't other option as doing this row-by-row. You can use transaction to expedite this (to avoid multiple log updates). Another option is to have a stored proc that would insert and return a list of inserted Ids, using `OUTPUT` statement.

Comment: I could not quite follow up. Is there any code sample you could refer me to please?

Comment: @Mike Dotnet - here you can find about `OUTPUT` statement that can be used with `INSERT` to retrieve IDs that were auto-generated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx